# Python regex group search returns only the first match

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the contents of the numbered list. Please check the following url: https://regex101.com/r/oS0yT5/1

```
string = @BarsAndMelody #3thingsthatmakeyousmile #1) @livingleondre #2) Leondre and Charlie #3) chocolate  ☺️   please notice me  it's my birthday
```

The following code extracts only the first match:

```
p = re.compile("(?<=[#\s][\d][\)\.\:][\s])(.*?)(?=[#][\d][\)\.\:][\s])")
x = p.search(string)
x.group(1)
```

The above code returns the first match: `@livingleondre` using x.group(2) returns `No such group error`. 
As shown in the above given [url](https://regex101.com/r/oS0yT5/1) how can I extract other contents of the group
Desired output: `@livingleondre` , `Leondre and Charlie`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `re.findall` to find *all* the matches, not only the first:

```
string = "@BarsAndMelody #3thingsthatmakeyousmile #1) @livingleondre #2) Leondre and Charlie #3) chocolate  ☺️   please notice me  it's my birthday"
p = re.findall("(?<=[#\s][\d][\)\.\:][\s])(.*?)(?=[#][\d][\)\.\:][\s])",string)
print p[0]
print p[1]
```

Also, you could simplify the regex to this:

```
(?<=[#\s]\d[).:]\s)(.*?)(?=#\d[).:]\s)
```

Since there's no need to escape anything inside `[...]` and you can omit `[...]` around single characters.